# Node.js compiles files I did not require. How does that work under the hood?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am incurring an error I fail to understand in node.js.
I have a file which I did not require at all but finds it way in the module system loading and compiling which I do not want as it would be served on the client only.

Here is the setup with babel:

**bootstrap.js**

```
require('babel/register');
require('./server/index');
```

The index.js has nothing related to **main.jsx**. Nevertheless here are its imported modules:

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes';
import path from 'path';
```

But somehow node.js tries to load and compile ***main.jsx*** which gives me error as such:

```
/home/minheq/Git/react_app/node_modules/react/lib/invariant.js:49
throw error;
^

Error: Invariant Violation: You cannot use <HistoryLocation> without a DOM
at invariant (/home/minheq/Git/react_app/node_modules/react/lib/invariant.js:42:15)
at createRouter (/home/minheq/Git/react_app/node_modules/react-router/lib/createRouter.js:131:5)
at Object.runRouter [as run] (/home/minheq/Git/react_app/node_modules/react-router/lib/runRouter.js:40:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/minheq/Git/react_app/app/main.jsx:6:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:430:26)
at normalLoader (/home/minheq/Git/react_app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .jsx] (/home/minheq/Git/react_app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
```

Particularly this line:

```
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/minheq/Git/react_app/app/main.jsx:6:10)'
```

Any reference on how that happens perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using react?

Comment: that is correct, trying to setup webpack with multi entry-points, express and react router for ultimate setup

Comment: You're importing `main.jsx` from somewhere, it won't just randomly be imported for no reason. Perhaps it comes from your routes you're importing? See this: `react-router/lib/runRouter.js`.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/528

Comment: You are right, I can see a chain of other requires that uses main.jsx on the server, and indeed it comes from routes. Thanks for a lead and reference!

Comment: No problem, glad to point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The importation of `main.jsx` comes from this line:

```
import routes from './routes';
```

In your error stacktrace, you'll see this:

```
react-router/lib/runRouter.js
```

Regarding the `Invariant Violation`, see [this issue on Github](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/528).